# Setting torch.nn.linear() diagonal elements zero

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to build a model with a layer of `torch.nn.linear` with same input size and output size, so the layer would be square matrix. In this model, I want the diagonal elements of this matrix fixed to zero. Which means, during training, I don't want the diagonal elements to be changed from zero. I could only think of adding some kind of step that change diag elements to zero for each training epoch, but I am not sure if this is valid or efficient way. Is there a definite way of making this kind of layer which can ensure that the diagonal elements don't change?

Sorry if my question is weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always implement your own layers. Note that all custom layers should be implemented as classes derived from [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.nn.Module.html). For example:

```py
class LinearWithZeroDiagonal(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, num_features, bias):
    super(LinearWithZeroDiagonal, self).__init__()
    self.base_linear_layer = nn.Linear(num_features, num_features, bias)
    
  def forward(self, x):
    # first, make sure the diagonal is zero
    with torch.no_grad():
      self.base_linear_layer.weight.fill_diagonal_(0.)
    return self.base_linear_layer(x)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add `super(LinearWithZeroDiagonal, self).__init__()` for my model but otherwise I think it works perfectly fine!